# Python: Nosetests: Is it possible to set attributes/tags in the setup_class method during run time?

Tags: python, nosetests

I want to setup a test suite wherein I will read a json file in setup_class method and in that json file I will mention which tests should run and which tests should not run. So with this approach I can mention which test cases to run by altering the json file only and not touching the test suite.

But in the setup_class method when I try to do the following:-

```
class TestCPU:
    testme=False

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
       cls.test_core.testme=True

    def test_core(self):
       print 'Test CPU Core'
       assert 1
```

Executing below command:-

```
   nosetests -s -a testme
```

It gives following error:-

```
   File "/home/murtuza/HWTestCert/testCPU.py", line 7, in setup_class
   cls.test_core.testme=False
   AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'testme'
```

So, is it possible to set the attributes of test methods during setup_class?

Comment: This seems to be great@Murtuuuuuu :)

Answer (score 1):

The way it is defined, `testme` is a member of the TestCPU class, and the `<unbound method TestCPU.test_core>` has no idea about this attribute. You can inject nose attribute by using `cls.test_core.__dict__['testme']=True`. However, the attributes are checked before your `setup_class` method is called, so even though the attribute will be set, your test will be skipped. But you can certainly decorate your test with attributes on import, like this:

```
import unittest

class TestCPU(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_core(self):
       print 'Test CPU Core'
       assert 1

TestCPU.test_core.__dict__['testme']=True
```

You may also want to try `--pdb` option to nosetests, it will bring out debugger on error so that you can dive in to see what is wrong. It is definitely my second favorite thing in life.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are multiple ways to achieve this, but here is one way you can do it.

Inside your test class, create a method that reads in your JSON file and creates a global array for methods to be skipped for testing - `skiptests`

All you need to do now is use a setup decorator for every test case method in your suite. Within this decorator, check if the current function is in `skiptests`. If so, call nosetests' custom decorator `nose.tools.nottest` which is used to skip a test. Otherwise, return the function being tested.

To put it in code:

```
def setup_test_method1(func):
    if func.__name__ not in skiptests:
        return func
    else:
        return nose.tools.nottest(func)


@with_setup(setup_test_method1)
def test_method1():
    pass
```

I have not tested this code, but I think we can invoke a decorator within another decorator. In which case this could work.